# how to interpret output tensor data packing in tensorflow lite c++?

Tags: c++, tensorflow-lite

I am working on a tensorflow-lite model in c++ (I have it working python already) and I was confused about how my output data is packed. I couldn't find any references in the documentation. I looked in the tflite source and learned I could get the output dimension of my tensor using dims for example

```
for(int i=0; i < size; i++){
print("%d\n", out_tensor->dims->data[i]);
}
```

This gives me:

```
1
96
96
14
```

Which is exactly what I know the output data to be. It is a 96x96 grid where each grid element is 14 floats. What I don't understand is how to get this data out properly. At first we assumed it was flat and pulled it out like this:

```
  const float* output = interpreter->typed_output_tensor<float>(0);

  for (int j = 0; j < num_values; ++j) {
    output_data_flat[out_idx++] = output[j];
  }
```

But this did not seem to come out right.  What is the right or at least a clean way to unpack this output data?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TensorFlow Lite tensor data is stored in a continuous manner, which means that you can assume as it is flatten.

In the other words, you can assume `interpreter->typed_output_tensor<float>(0)` as float[1][96][96][14].